# PHP Convert String Matrix Into Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

Assume I have a `string` formatted like:

```
293545
974256
947276
```

And I want to convert that into a `PHP` two dimensional array, where the newlines are separate rows, and the number value `(single character)` is each element in the array. What is the `most efficient` way to do this assuming that the string may grow to 500x500.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about efficiency, but the below is simple and easily readable.

```
function matrix_to_array($matrix) {
  $matrix = explode("\n", $matrix);
  $matrix = array_map("str_split", $matrix);
  return $matrix;
}
```

If the above (or any other PHP implementation) turns out to be too slow, it can often be a good idea to out-source computation-heavy algorithms to external C (or other low-level, compiled language) programs.